# name was defined in resolvers, but enum is not in schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollo-server

with appolo server 2 beta,

I have a resolver like:

```
Travaux: new GraphQLEnumType({
  name: 'Travaux',
  values: {
    ins: { value: 'en instruction' },
    val: { value: 'valide' },
    ech: { value: 'échu' }
  }
})
```

and a Schema

```
gql`
  type Query {
    titre(id: String!): Titre
  }

  type Titre {
    travaux: Travaux
  }

  enum Travaux {
    ins
    val
    ech
  }
`
```

This makes an error:

`Travaux.name was defined in resolvers, but enum is not in schema`

If I remove the `Travaux` resolver, it works… 
What is arong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolver has to be:

```
Travaux = {
  ins: 'en instruction',
  val: 'valide',
  ech: 'échu'
}
```